# intense integral using DCT

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

Is this solution correct?

Determine the following integral: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_6^n(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} dx.$$

We will appeal to the DCT. First note that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x.$$
Then we can define $f_n:= (1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} $ and it is pretty clear to see that
$$f_n \rightarrow \chi_{[6,\infty)} e^{-x}$$
a.e., then the integrable function $g$ can be defined as $g(x)=\chi_{[0,\infty)} e^{-x}$ and we clearly have that $g(x)$ is an upper bound for the $f_n$ thus by the DCT, the given integral converges to the integral of $\chi_{[6,\infty)}e^{-x}$, that is,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_6^n(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} dx = \int_6^\infty e^{-x} dx$$
and the RHS here is just $e^{-6}$. Thus
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_6^n(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} dx= e^{-6}$$
which completes the integral evaluation.

Comment: Yo should say how you get $(0 \leq )f_n(x) \leq \chi_{[0,\infty)} e^{-x}$.

Comment: ah you mean justify this step as well? got it thanks! other than that ok?

Comment: Yes, everything else is fine.

Comment: question, the $f_n$ being bounded above by $g$ does it have to do with the fact that $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x) \ge \chi_{[6,\infty)}(x)$? for every $x$. Also, if $f_n$ non-negative because it is product of non-negative functions so by zero product property?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use MCT here rather than DCT since it's not easy to justify the function is controlled by $\exp(-x)$

For MCT, using AM-GM inequality
$$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n\bullet1\leq(\frac{n(1+\frac{x}{n})+1}{n+1})^{n+1}=(1+\frac{x}{n+1})^{n+1}$$